# How can I identify the complement in a probability problem?

Tags: probability

Sometimes the complement it's quite obvious, but there are some cases when I don't know if I'm interpreting correctly the probabilities.

For example: 
Santa Claus packs toys. If a random box is selected, there are 80% probabilities that the box has no defective toy, 15% probabilities that the box has one defective toy and 5% probabilities that the box has 2 defective toys.

If I consider P(2) = 0.05, then its complement is 0.95. But what situation does this represent? That a box has 2 toys that are not defective?

Comment: keep Demorgan's laws in mind. The complement of A and B is the complement of A or the complement of B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be either $0$ and $1$ and $2$ defects.

$$\{0,1,2\}$$

The complement event is a randomly chosen box doesn't have exactly $2$ defective toys.

$$\{0,1,\color{red}2\}$$

In this particular context, since there are at most $2$ defects, the complement event is a randomly picked box has at most $1$ defects.

$$\{\color{blue}{0,1},2\}$$

Some diagrams might help, you don't have to use a shorten description such as "at most $1$ defects", you can also describe it as "$0$ or $1$ defect."